# Drawing to NSView within NSMenuItem is darkened

Tags: draw, nsview, nsmenuitem

I am drawing a coloured circle within an NSView that is contained in an NSMenuItem. When I do so, the circle is drawn in a darker colour to the one I specify and when I add a subview with no drawing code, the area occupied by that view is drawn in the true colour, as illustrated by the image. Could someone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Many Thanks, Ben.

[image]